# OwinStartup not Starting ... Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I have the following class on an ASP.NET MVC 5 site:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MVCSite.Startup))]
namespace MVCSite {

  public partial class Startup {

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder application) {

      application.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
      });

      application.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    }
  }
}
```

And on Web.Config I have the following:

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>
```

I have a breakpoint inside Startup.Configuration but this does not fire ...

Any idea why?

Comment: `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>` Presumably you want `AutomaticAppStartup` to be `true` ? Note that [these instructions](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) are not step-by-step. The first list shows you different options.

Comment: 1) As mentioned by @ta.speot.is you may want to give a true value to the owin:AutomaticAppStartup appSetting. 2) Do you have Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb nuget package installed in your project? This package is required for the Startup class to be picked up. You can check out this tutorial for more information : http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem ... I miss interpret the information on owin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OwinStartup not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203982/owinstartup-not-firing)

Answer (score 34):

It's usually happend because **SystemWeb** package is not installed on your project.

*Use this command at your Package Manager Console:*

> **Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb**

In the other hand you may use this configuration on your **app.config** or **web.config** if the above solution is not work:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: This has saved me from hours of struggle. Thanks so much.

Comment: you're welcome very much 

Answer (score 16):

Using

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"/>
```

Is the answer.

Comment: I was having the same issue as the OP. I had my `Startup` class, as well as the OWIN attributes on it. I had also installed the `Owin.Host.SystemWeb` package.  I didn't look at the web.config for this attribute, because I had never set it to fault. I assumed the package installation would set things up for me - I was wrong. Make sure you check for this configuration setting!

Comment: Where is it supposed to be in the config file?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: it is supposed to be in `<appSettings><add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" /></appSettings>` block

Comment: `Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`

SystemWeb package is not installed on your project

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MVCSite.Startup))]` and give a shot

Comment: The question has been answered by way of comments which the author has agreed to.