# OWIN StartUp not working

Tags: c#, owin

I've declared the following in my application:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup("MyClass", typeof(MyClass), "ConfigureOwin")]
```

Defined a startup class:

```
public class MyClass {

    public void ConfigureOwin(IAppBuilder appBuilder) {

    }

}
```

And start owin like this:

```
WebApp.Start<MyClass>("baseUri");
```

However, it's not working. WebApp always tries to look for a method named 'Configuration' even if I define to look for something else. What could I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OwinStartup not Starting ... Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760545/owinstartup-not-starting-why)

Comment: This is dublicate. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20204884/3558141

Answer (score 42):

For me, I needed to add `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` as a reference.  (Click **Manage Nuget Packages** and search for it.)

Thanks to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/praburaj/archive/2013/12/02/owin-startup-class-not-detected.aspx) for the tip.

I ran into this issue because I migrated from Web API to Web API with [OWIN middleware for ADFS authentication](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/).

Comment: I was trying to add the packages to get a vanilla MVC app to use the OAuth middleware.  Got most of the OWIN installed, however, without Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, the Startup.cs wasn't running, just takin up space.

Comment: I _always_ forget that one :-(

Answer (score 25):

If you're using `optimizeCompilations="true"` in your `web.config` you may need to set it to `false` and back to `true`.

Comment: This worked for me. Is this a temporary ASP.NET files thing??

Comment: Also solved the issue for me. Change `optimizeCompilations` to `false`, run your app, then switch back to `true`. It's a dumb solution but one that works!

Comment: This.  Went through a bunch of other answers and this is the only thing that worked!

Comment: This worked!  Why did it work?  I'm so happy right now I logged in just to upvote this --- thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Both [`OwinStartupAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.owinstartupattribute.aspx) and [`WebApp.Start<T>(StartOptions)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn300219.aspx) are ways to specify what class to use to configure the OWIN pipeline, both will assume that the specified type has a method with the signature `Configuration(IAppBuilder)`.

However, the `OwinStartupAttribute` has overloads to specify an optional *method name*. AFAIK there's no overload to specify method name when using the `WebApp.Start<T>` method.

The `OwinStartupAttribute` is most useful when you have an external component that "kickstarts" the OWIN pipeline, e.g. an ASP.NET handler (using [Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb)) or Helios (using [Microsoft.Owin.Host.IIS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.IIS)). If you're self-hosting (using [Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener)), it's best to use the `WebApp.Start` methods.

Here's a great resource on [OWIN Startup Class Detection](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection).

Comment: Ah, however it seems that automatic startup doesn't really work in self hosted processes. Removing WebApp.Start<T> just with OwinStartupAttribute and app.config does absolutely nothing.

Comment: You're correct. There's nothing to "kickstart" the application when self-hosting (in a web scenario it would be an ASP.NET handler or Helios (pure IIS)). If you're self-hosting, I'd go with the `WebApp.Start<T>` approach and just stick to the conventions :)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `OwinStartupAttribute` needs to be kick started by the ASP.Net handler when hosted in IIS

Answer (score 2):

In your web.config `appSettings`, try adding this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are various reasons for startup.cs not trigger, One common issue is the startup.cs runs successfully, but the debugger does not fire up, Assuming you have all components installed, then it could be the web project url is assigned to work with an external host, change that to IIS Express will detect it...

go to Web Project settings, Web, then in the servers section choose IIS express.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I added  Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb as a reference, later add startup class, but in my case, I need to change the order of the reference in the  .csproj file, put it in the first positions, and It works for me.

[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSq1B.png)