# MVC project startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, global-asax

I have an existing MVC project which has a knockout front end and a WebAPI back end.

Due to a change in requirements I had to remove all the back end files from the project, leaving only the front end files.

Now I need to a WebAPI controller back into the project.

In order to configure the WebAPI I need to find an entry point into the C# code to trigger the configuration methods.

My understanding is that if the project has a Global.asax file, the `Application_Start()` will automatically be fired on start up. And also if I have a startup.cs file with an `owinStartup` property, this will also be triggered by default.

So I copied both these files from another project and edited as required, but neither files are being triggered on startup.

I assume I am missing some kind of configuration, but am not sure what?

Here is my startup.cs file:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ClearviewLocal_ONFrontEnd_Rest.Startup))]
namespace ClearviewLocal_ONFrontEnd_Rest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Application startup
    /// </summary>
    public class Startup
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Configure app
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app">Owin AppBuilder</param>
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {         
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();         //breakpoint here that is not being hit
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the Global.asax file:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ClearviewLocal_ONFrontEnd_Rest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration(); //Breakpoint here            
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked at the answer to this question: [OwinStartup not Starting ... Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760545/owinstartup-not-starting-why) but this code was never in the Web.Config

Also, I have not removed any references from the project

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happened for you to have to get rid of all the 'back end' files?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ The WebAPI calls got moved out into another project as they were required by other projects aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer to this question [OwinStartup not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203982/owinstartup-not-firing) seems to have solved my issue:

"
Make sure you have installed Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb package in the project. This package is needed for startup detection in IIS hosted applications.
"